# Rails ActiveRecord - Best way to perform an include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections
  has_many :users, :through => :collections
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections
  has_many :books, :through => :collections
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm trying to display a list of the books and have a link to either add or remove from the user's collection.  I can't quite figure out the best syntax to do this.

For example, if I do the following:

Controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end
end
```

View

```
...
<% if book.users.include?(current_user) %>
...
```

or obviously the inverse...

```
...
<% if current_user.books.include?(book) %>
...
```

Then queries are sent for each book to check on that include? which is wasteful.  I was thinking of adding the users or collections to the :include on the Book.all, but I'm not sure this is the best way.  Effectively all I need is the book object and just a boolean column of whether or not the current user has the book in their collection, but I'm not sure how to forumlate the query in order to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

-Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a gem([select_extra_columns](http://github.com/kandadaboggu/select_extra_columns)) for returning join/calculated/aggregate columns in a ActiveRecord finders. Using this gem, you will be able to get the book details and the flag `indicating if the current user has the book` in one query.

In your User model register the `select_extra_columns` feature.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  select_extra_columns
  has_many :collections
  has_many :users, :through => :collections
end
```

Now in your controller add this line:

```
@books = Book.all(
           :select => "books.*, IF(collections.id, 1, 0) AS belongs_to_user",
           :extra_columns => {:belongs_to_user => :boolean},
           :joins => "LEFT OUTER JOIN collections 
                        ON book.id = collections.book_id AND 
                           collections.user_id = #{current_user.id}"
          )
```

Now in your view you can do the following.

```
book.belongs_to_user?
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to go, but I'm having an issue with mixing :joins and :includes in the same find.  My @books = Book.all is really @books = Book.all(:include => [:authors, ...])

Comment: You can use `include` instead of `joins`. Don't have to use them both.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to to want 2 SQL queries, and O(1) based lookups (probably irrelevant, but it's the principle) to check if they have the book.

The initial calls.

```
@books = Book.all
@user = User.find(params[:id], :include => :collections)
```

Next, you're going to want to write the books the user has into a hash for constant time lookup (if people won't ever have many books, just doing an array.include? is fine).

```
@user_has_books = Hash.new
@user.collections.each{|c|@user_has_books[c.book_id] = true}
```

And on the display end:

```
@books.each do |book|
  has_book = @user_has_books.has_key?(book.id)
end
```

I'd err away from caching the book_ids on the user object, simply because going this route can have some funny and unexpected consequences if you ever start serializing your user objects for whatever reason (i.e. memcached or a queue).

Edit: Loading intermediary collection instead of double loading books.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to make one call to get the book information and the Boolean flag indicating if the current user has the book. ActiveRecord finders doesn't allow you to return the join results from another table. We work around this problem by doing a trick.

In your `Book` model add this method.

```
def self.extended_book
  self.columns # load the column definition
  @extended_user ||= self.clone.tap do |klass| 
      klass.columns << (klass.columns_hash["belongs_to_user"] =  
                      ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(
                          "belongs_to_user", false, "boolean"))
  end # add a dummy column to the cloned class
end
```

In your controller use the following code:

```
@books = Book.extended_book.all(
           :select => "books.*, IF(collections.id, 1, 0) AS belongs_to_user",  
           :joins => "LEFT OUTER JOIN collections 
                        ON book.id = collections.book_id AND 
                           collections.user_id = #{current_user.id}"
          )
```

Now in your view you can do the following.

```
book.belongs_to_user?
```

**Explanation:**

In the `extended_book` method you are creating a copy of Book class and adding a dummy column `belongs_to_user` to the hash. During the query extra join column is not rejected as it exists in the columns_hash. You should use the `extended_book` only for querying.
If you use it for CRUD operations DB will throw error.

Answer (score -1):

Use `exists?` on the association as it is direct SQL call. The association array is NOT loaded to perform these checks.

```
books.users.exists?(current_user)
```

This is the SQL executed by Rails.

```
SELECT `users`.id FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `collections` ON `users`.id = `collections`.user_id 
WHERE (`users`.`id` = 2) AND ((`collections`.book_id = 1)) LIMIT 1
```

In the above SQL `current_user` id = 2 and `book` id is 1

```
current_user.books.exists?(book)
```

This is the SQL executed by Rails.

```
SELECT `books`.id FROM `books` 
INNER JOIN `collections` ON `books`.id = `collections`.book_id 
WHERE (`books`.`id` = 3) AND ((`collections`.user_id = 4)) LIMIT 1
```

In the above SQL `current_user` id = 4 and `book` id is 3

For more details, refer to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001833) of the `exists?` method in a `:has_many` association.

**Edit:** I have included additional information to validate my answer.

Comment: I am surprised that my answer is voted down. This solution is certainly efficient. I would love to know the reason for the down vote.

Comment: Your solution works, but is not efficient/good practice. It defeats the purpose of an :include, which is to minimise round trips to the database. Using exists? requires one call per book (the old 1+N queries problem). If there are a hundred books, that's 100 round trips to the database server and 100 queries that have to have their query plan compiled, executed and returned over the network.

Comment: I thought the user wanted improvement to the 'include?' call he was making. I must have misread the question.

Comment: I have added a new solution to this question. New solution requires one query to return everything.

Comment: Your solution is efficient if there is only 1 book. 2 queries are done: one to retrieve the user, and 1 to determine if the book is part of the user's collection. If there are 3 books, then 4 queries are needed: 1 to get the user, 3 to get the book membership information. 100 books? 101 queries: 1 for the user, 100 for the books. N+1 queries will be done. The books must be retrieved in a single SQL query to prevent this problem, which is what :include does, or even Jose Frenandez's solution too (2 queries total, irrespective of the number of books).

Comment: If you read the question the user is asking for `Best way to perform an include?`. My answer would be different if the question was for `:include` instead of `include?`. I was giving him a way to optimize the `books.include?(user)` call. I have added another answer to address the N+1 issue.

Comment: If you are going to use the gem I suggested, get the latest version. I have fixed several bugs last night.

Answer (score -1):

I would first create an instance method in the User model that 'caches' the all the Book ID's in his collection:

```
def book_ids
  @book_ids ||= self.books.all(:select => "id").map(&:id)
end
```

This will only execute the SQL query once per controller request.  Then create another instance method on the User model that takes a book_id as a parameter and checks to see if its included in his book collection.

```
def has_book?(book_id)
  book_ids.include?(book_id)
end
```

Then while you iterate through the books:

```
<% if current_user.has_book?(book.id) %>
```

Only 2 SQL queries for that controller request :)

Comment: I'd be very interested too to know why the negative vote, as this solution is pretty good. Not how I'd have done it, but still, a good solution.